# Архитектура расширения. Дополнение логики библиотеки

Tags: логика, архитектура

Подскажите логику,

- Есть библиотека с доступными исходными кодами А, и программа B которая использует эту библиотеку.
- В одном из компонентов библиотеки А существует некий класс С в котором реализован метод F.
- Указанный метод F реализует требуемую логику для программы B лишь частично, и необходимо эту логику как-нибудь дополнить.

Вопрос: как это **лучше** всего сделать ?

т.к. метод F класса C вызывается различными компонентами библиотеки А, и собственно обращение к нему от программы B не требуется, то соответственно простым расширением класса воде бы не выкрутиться, а копаться в модуле не совсем хорошо (хотя конечно это проще и быстрее).
может как-то с подмешиванием mixin/traits ? или наращиванием логики типа декораторов ? только вот все же библиотеку трогать **не хотелось бы** -_-

Comment: декоратор - хорошая идея, почему бы и нет? скорее всего это так и будет..

Comment: я вот еще о чем, в любом случаи нужно будет делать подготовку в самой библиотеке ?
если тот же декоратор, то так или иначе нужно произвести некоторые дополнения в класс библиотеки, т.к. нужно перегрузить метод для самой библиотеки, для программы он как таковой не нужен

Программа использует только результат работы библиотеки(которая в одном из своих шагов использует этот метод, который нужно перегрузить).
может есть более изощренные(но более эффективные) методы, с которыми еще не довелось повстречаться

Comment: @btree Правильное использование паттерна `Decorator` не требует внесений в исходный код библиотеки, за исключением случаев, когда класс, который используется в качестве базового для декоратора, помечен как `sealed` (в этом случае обычно стоит задуматься, почему так произошло, и из каких соображений возник этот самый `sealed`).

Comment: @btree По поводу вопроса — не хватает детализации постановки задачи. Что вы подразумеваете под "дополнить"? Можно ли дополнить эту функциональность, не изменяя контракта и вообще не прикасаясь к методу `F`? Если да, то введите в рамках программы `B` класс `C_Helper`, который вызовет `F,` а также совершит необходимые **дополнительные действия.** Если нет, то выпиливайте из метода `F` функциональность, которую нужно подменить, в `protected` метод, создавайте в программе `B` наследника `C` и изменяйте поведение выделенного `protected` метода. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: ок, детализирую:

библиотека от Delta Software - Remote Call Framework
Требуется модификация логики инкапсулированную в метод processJsonRpcRequest(); объявленный в RcfSession.hpp и реализованный в RcfServer.cpp void RcfSession::processJsonRpcRequest(){}
Можете увидеть воочию, исходники доступны с их сайта.

В программе связываются методы которые агрегируют запросы/ответы клиента, во время обработки вызываются соответствующие методы библиотеки, один из которых требует некоторого дополнения/изменения, то что требуется разумеется не суть важно, но возьмем например блоки перехвата исключений...

Comment: ну в общем если более удачных решений нет, то скорей всего придется обычным расширением делать, и соответственен для всех его зависимостей (т.к. оперированием логики идет через класс сервера, и соотвтесвенно как уже написано в вопросе просто расширить сессию соответственно ничего не выйдет)

Вариант не нравиться, но чего-то другого не насмекалил, возможно еще уважаемый @Котик_хочет_кушать чего эффективнее посоветует -_-